# What is the future of serviceNow developer and outSystems developer jobs as compared to actual coding jobs considering AI?

Tags: servicenow, outsystems, xenocode

"I'm considering pursuing a career path in software development, particularly in areas like ServiceNow and OutSystems development. However, I'm curious about how these roles might evolve in comparison to more traditional coding jobs, especially with the advancements in artificial intelligence (AI).

Specifically, I'd like to understand:

1. How the demand for ServiceNow and OutSystems developers might change in the coming years compared to roles focused on general programming languages and frameworks.
2. Whether AI technologies are expected to significantly impact the tasks performed by ServiceNow and       OutSystems developers, potentially altering the nature of these roles.
3. Any emerging trends or shifts in the job market that could influence the career prospects for professionals specializing in these platforms.